# I do not see the genymotion plugin installed in android studio

Tags: android, genymotion

install the genymotion plugin but it does not show up in android studio
help me please!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, be more specific. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: install the genymotion plugin but it is not installed in the toolbar. I wanted to know what is due? because the plugin should appear after installing it

Comment: @Santiago Lopez  Hi, I have same issue.  Did you ever find a solution to fix the missing Genymotion toolbar icon?

Answer (score 4):

Hope you are doing well i just solved the problem. I am also having the same problem whole Day.Just figured out the exact solution.Click the "view" On menu bar then select "toolbar" make sure that its checked and you are all done and you will see the "genymotion device manager" icon On the toolbar. Then click the "genymotion device manager" , it will ask for "Genymotion" Location Browse and Select the genymotion folder under "genymobile" and you are done.Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Check installation instructions, specifically point 3: https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/

You have to enable the toolbar.